# Stubbing ActiveRecord dynamic finders with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, rspec2

How can I setup the following models/specs for mocking in my controller specs.

Here are the models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorites
end

class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :place
end

class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorites, :as => :favorable
end
```

Then at some point a place will be checked to see if it's currently a favorite

```
@favorite = @current_user.favorites.find_by_place_id(@place.id)
```

Now, I want to mock a user for some examples

```
it "should be success" do
  user = double("User")
  user.stub(:favorites)
  get :show, :id => "1081651"
  response.should be_success
end
```

But, I end up with

```
undefined method `find_by_place_id' for nil:NilClass
```

What can I do with :favorites to help it pass.  Since the dynamic finder is used, I'm not sure how to properly mock that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use null object stub, which will ignore all unexpected messages:

```
user.stub(:favorites).and_return(double.as_null_object)
```

Another way is to use `stub_chain` method:

```
user.stub_chain(:favorites, :find_by_place_id)
```

Comment: I tried various versions of that and returning nil from the :favorites stub, but no luck.  The problem isn't that the method isn't expected, it's that it needs to return something that the find_by_place_id can operate on, and it can't operate on a nil.

Comment: @RyanW right, try returning null object from stubbed `favorites` method. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
favorite = double('Favorite')
user.stub_chain(:favorites, :find_by_place_id) { favorite }
```